# Filipino citizen married to US citizen, Filipino has US Green Card, traveling to UK- is UK visa needed?

Tags: filipino-citizens

I'm a Filipino citizen and my husband is a US citizen. I have US Green Cards (Permanent Resident visa)

We have a 15 month old baby girl who is a US Citizen.

We are wanting to visit for holiday in the UK in June. Can you please advise what the UK will require visa of me given these circumstances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [you will need a visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/philippines/tourism/yes/no).  The UK (unlike Canada) does not have a visa exemption for US permanent residents.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea how long it will take to get a UK VISA under these circumstances?

Comment: @MigoSurf unfortunately, I do not.  I also note that it is not necessary to write "visa" in all caps; it's not an acronym or anything like that, just a normal word.  At least I can say that your LPR status in the US should help your application considerably, as will your having a well established family life in the US, so your application will probably be handled fairly routinely and therefore relatively quickly.  But I do not know anything about the processing times, I'm afraid.